# paypal Java Rest API Getting Shipping Information before paymentexecution

Tags: java, rest, paypal

I am using the Paypal Java Rest API.

I build a payment object.
I run the  payment.create(accessToken).
Then send the user off to paypal.
The user returns from paypal after entering shipping and payment information.
The user comes back to my site.

I then execute  Payment p = Payment.get(accessToken, paymentId);

I get the payment but it does not have the shipping information.
I can get the shipping information if I:
PaymentExecution paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution(payerID);
Payment executedPayment = createdPayment.execute(accessToken, paymentExecution);

Then the payment object will have all information about the transaction.

I don't want to execute the payment yet.  I just want the shipping information so I can show shipping options.  Then after the user accepts the order I can execute the payment (either sale or auth).

I just want the shipping information when the customer returns to my site before taking or authorizing the payment.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this time, the shipping information is only returned in the Execution response. There are discussions to modify this for future releases.